# Liferay IFrame popups

Tags: iframe, popup, liferay, liferay-6

I am currently loading a website inside of a liferay iframe portlet.

Upon clicking one of the links in the website a popup is generated that loads in a new browser tab. Is there a way to prevent the link from opening as a popup and instead opening inside of the portlet?

Answer (score 2):

That's the downside of using an iframe. The question is actually completely unrelated to liferay - or at least independent. You might get more audience when you rephrase it in a liferay independent way.

As you mention Liferay, you might want to try the WebProxy portlet: Here you can process the HTML generated by the server and change/rewrite the code that opens new windows. But it's definitely more complicated than "just" using an iframe. Also, with WebProxy, it's the server that requests the external page, rewrites and sends it to the browser. With the iframe, the browser connects directly to your thirdparty system.

You might be lucky to be able to process the DOM (e.g. rewrite the iframe page) if both sites live on the same domain. But somebody else would have to answer with the details on how exactly to do this and what the javascript security implications are when you're changing documents across iframe boundaries